# Simulate touchmove inertia with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, touch, dom-events

The problem is that during the inertia following a touchmove event, the Javascript seems to pause and the UI waits until the inertia has ended before redrawing.

I would like animations to happen during the touchmove / inertia. Is there a JS library or plugin that prevents the default event and then simulates it effectively?

Answer (score 1):

Realizing it is more than a year since you asked, this might be what you're looking for. I just wrote a jQuery 'plugin' (more a script) that handles touch events and simulates momentum scrolling. You can find the script and an elaborate explanation at http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/simulate-momentum-scrolling-in-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Execution of JavaScript pauses, as you've noticed, when inertia scroll is active.

I don't know whether it can be disabled (haven't heard of it). But you could try using e.g overflow:hidden on the area you don't want to be scrolled and then use http://cubiq.org/iscroll or such to simulate scrolling behavior.